# Can you use RegAsm with an executable?

Tags: c#, .net, regasm

I have an exe that I want to register. I have the type library by using the tlbexp tool, but when I try and regasm the executable, I get an `error RA0000`. Apparently the "operation is not supported"? I'm not sure what the cause of this could be. I've done a lot of other work with regasm for various class libraries but never with executables. So is it even possible? And if so, do you have to use a different method?

Comment: If I use the version of regasm.exe in my .NET Framework v2.0.50727 folder, it works, but I get a warning instead.

Answer (score 0):

All the information I have seen does not allow you to register executables as COM operable (even though I know you can just call methods inside the executable without actually starting it).  Have you tried changing the output type of your executable to a class library and registering then?